# Exponential Smoothing - how to choose alpha, beta, gamma

Tags: python

I am trying to do exponential smoothing in python with statsmodels.tsa.api Exonential Smoothing and Holt (Triple and Double).
I was wondering how to choose my smoothing_level, smoothing_slope and smoothing_seasonal (alpha, beta, gamma).

So far I manually put different values in the fit function, run the model and compared results.

The GridSearhCV function only works with sklearn.models, so I can't use it in this case I guess.

Is there another way to to gridsearch or choose the right parameters?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find the "correct" alpha, beta, and gamma for your model using [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize).

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing
from scipy.optimize import minimize

series = pd.Series([10.21,23.01,10.97,14.59,29.4,16.8,18.86,38.9,18.61,24.2,48.9,22.78])

# Create model
ets_model = ExponentialSmoothing(series, trend='add', seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods = 3)

# Create initial guess, each element in array represents your alpha, beta, gamma.
x0 = [.2,.2,.2]

# Create fit, and return SSE, which we will optimize for
def model(x):
    ets_fit = ets_model.fit(smoothing_level = x[0], smoothing_trend = x[1], smoothing_seasonal = x[2])
    return ets_fit.sse

solution = minimize(model, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds = ((0,1),(0,1),(0,1)))

#Print the values which will minimize your SSE.
print(solution.x)
```